# How to configure class path of a Web app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classloader

Is it possible to add JAR files to class path of a Web app so the servlets can use latest version of classes at run time?  if the answer is positive how can we do that? thanks

Comment: Actually I mean doing this at run time. I have a Web APP which was designed to download latest version of Servlets and register them to container each time container was started. is that possible?

Comment: just curious: why do you need to add jar file to class path during runtime? since jar lib is only used during compilation

Comment: @Thai Tran: is a distributed system sharing one DB server, I have code processing DB alone. with JPA entities and other utility classes serialized and sent to distributed nodes. I want them to be all synchronized each time when entity and util classes are updated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure. WAR can contain JARs.
Put them in 
`WEB-INF/lib`
and it will work.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your .jar libraries in `/webproject/web/WEB-INF/lib/` folder.
With best regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse,then right click on the project go to **properties>Java Build path>Add external jar** and then select your jar file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's not about environment or classpath configurations. it is expected to work at run time